# How to check if int array object is empty in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, int

I have an array of int grades[5].
I have a loop that checks the objects of the array one by one to see if they're empty.
I used:

```
if (grades[i] != null)
```

I get an error message that an int object is never "null" and therefor this expression always returns "true."
If not "null," how do I check to see if a specific object in the array is empty?

Thanx a lot for the help!

Comment: Define empty, `int` is a value type, hence it can't be null, so your elements in `int` array can never be `null`, though your array could be `null`

Comment: Try this: `grades[0] = null;` - Compile. I guess this will answer your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you should check for the default value of `0` like so.

```
if (grades[i] != 0)
```

However, if `0` is a valid value in your use case and you are expecting to store `null` (i.e. grade not set ) then you should declare the array as of type nullable `int`. Like so.

```
int?[] grades
```

Then you can check for null value in individual items like so.

```
if (grades[i].HasValue )
{  
    // mean grades[i] is not null and has some int value inside it
}
```

Comment: I'd avoid the `0` approach if possible, since a grade of 0% might be a valid, if dismal, grade. And any "magic number" like `0` or `-1` or whatever is not going to be as obvious as `null` to mean "value is not set". So if your situation allows it (and it doesn't always, with existing databases and such) I'd lean toward @Shiva's second suggestion of going with `int?[]`.

Answer (score 5):

int is not a nullable type. If you want to be able to check an empty int, you must use a nullable int : `int?`.

Answer (score 4):

`int` is a non-nullable type, instead of being null it will have its default value of `0`. If you want to have an array of `int` that allows for nulls you can make use of a nullable int. `int?`

You could use it this way

```
int?[] grades = new int?[5];
if (grades[i].HasValue) //The way to check for != null
```

Then to retrieve the value it does not work like a traditional `int`.

```
int gradeValue = grades[i].Value;
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thanx!

Is there a down side to using int? instead of int if I want to check an empty object in the array?

Answer (score 2):

int should be nullable according to implement this.

Nullabele int array is creation can be done using this

```
int?[] grades = new int?[5];
```

You can check whether there is value using

```
grades[i].HasValue
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider making a validator class. Code above should be work on nullable types too.

```
public class ArrayObjectValidator<T>
{
public ArrayObjectValidator(T[] array)
{
    this.array = array;
}

private T[] array { get; set; }

public bool ValidateIndex(int index)
{
    bool result = false;

    if (array != null && array.Length > 0)
    {
        result = CheckItemAt(index);
    }

    return result;
}

private bool CheckItemAt(int index)
{
    return index >= 0 && index < array.Length && NullControl(index);
}

private bool NullControl(int index)
{
    return array[index] != null && array[index] is T;
}
}
```

you can use it as below;

```
int[] integerArray = new int[10]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};
ArrayObjectValidator<int> intArrayObjValidator = new ArrayObjectValidator<int>(integerArray);
bool isItemAtIndexFiveNullOrEmpty = integerArray.ValidateIndex(5);
```